# How to solve error in Raster calculator in ArcGIS 10.3?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, raster-calculator

I am not sure how to solve the error message to solve my raster calculator algorithm.

The process I am trying to run is to sum pixel values of two raster files of the same area but that represent different years.

The error message is found below:

```
Executing: RasterCalculator ""rice_v2_2000_india_new.tif" + "rice_v2_2001_india_new.tif"" F:\Rice_Fallow_Mapping\Data_Biradarsir\India_rice\Fallows\rice_paddy\rice_xiao_v2_india_newboundary\geographic\test
Start Time: Thu Sep 15 19:00:54 2016
Raster(r"rice_v2_2000_india_new.tif") + Raster(r"rice_v2_2001_india_new.tif")
ERROR 000539: Error running expression: rcexec() 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<expression>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 2, in rcexec
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from arcpy.toolbox import *
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\toolbox.py", line 355, in <module>
    from .management import Graph, GraphTemplate
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 26, in <module>
    import _management
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\_management.py", line 14, in <module>
    import _graph
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\_graph.py", line 27, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 180, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from type_check import *
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 8, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    import function_base
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\function_base.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .numeric import result_type, NaN, shares_memory, MAY_SHARE_BOUNDS, TooHardError
ImportError: cannot import name shares_memory
```

This is the output

```
Failed to execute (RasterCalculator).
Failed at Thu Sep 15 19:00:54 2016 (Elapsed Time: 0.03 seconds)
```

Comment: it would help if you laid out what you are trying to do in raster calculator then we will have a better chance at interpreting the error message. Please indicate what the algorithm is along with the process you have created including any custom code you might have created.

Comment: I just want to add pixel values of two raster files of the same area but different year. when I start to run, above error was shown.

Comment: Were you running the standard in ArcMap Raster calculator tool as shown here? http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/raster-calculator.htm

Comment: Yes, Arcmap raster calculator

Comment: I've seen this error before when trying to call Raster Calc from a script as well as when the syntax is incorrect...an alternative is to try Map Algebra tools instead

Comment: If you're trying to run the raster calculator from a script, note that the [help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/raster-calculator.htm) states ""*The Raster Calculator tool is intended for use in the application only as a GP tool dialog box or in ModelBuilder. It is not intended for use in scripting and is not available in the ArcPy Spatial Analyst module.*"

Answer (score 1):

Taking from the example given in the [ArcGIS help](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/spatial-analyst/arithmetic-plus-operator.htm) I would suggest trying the following code:

```
# Import system modules
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

# Set environment settings
env.workspace = "C:/mySamples"

# Set local variables
inRaster1 = Raster("rice_v2_2000_india_new.tif")
inRaster2 = Raster("rice_v2_2001_india_new.tif")

# Execute Plus
outPlus = inRaster1 + inRaster2

# Save the output
outPlus.save("F:\Rice_Fallow_Mapping\Data_Biradarsir\India_rice\Fallows\rice_paddy\rice_xiao_v2_india_newboundary\geographic\test")
```